# passing List<Integer> in webservices method written in java

Tags: web-services, soapui

I have written webservices in java.

```
public List<ReflexFundInfo> method(List<Integer> Ids ) {
        List<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
            //added few elements on that array
            return list;        
        }
```

Just want to check is this the right way to pass the LIST into the method?If I'll check the SOAP message i am getting like:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:dmo="http://com.test.org" xmlns:dfow="http://localhost:7011/LMX_WEB/services/WebServiceTest">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <dmo:method>
         <dmo:Ids>
            </dmo:Ids>
      </dmo:method>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Basically I am testing the webservices using SOAPUI Tool .

Answer (score 0):

your method takes `List` of `integers` as an input and returns back the `List` of `ReflexFundInfo`, If this is your intention , then you are doing right.